# Type or namespace name TSocket could not be found apache thrift C# Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, thrift

Screenshot of installed thrift package and Thrift.dll reference:

[image: Screenshot of installed thrift package and Thrift.dll reference]

I am trying to create a simple thrift client in Visual Studio 2019 using C#. I have generated the c# thrift bindings and everything else. However, I get "Type or namespace name "TSocket" could not be found". I have no other errors. Here is a snippet from my setup code:

```
// imports, namespaces
using System;
using System.Net;
using Thrift;
using Thrift.Transport;
using Thrift.Protocol;
  
TTransport socket1 = new TSocket("hostname", port);
TTransport transport = new TFramedTransport(socket1);
                
(more stuff .....)
```

I have no other issues with other references to thrift modules within the client. It just can't find "TSocket" somehow. I am super new to c# and thrift.

I am using `thrift 0.14.1` and have installed it using the NuGet packages add-on Visual Studio 2019.

What could be the problem? Thanks.
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69tmP.png)

After looking at, it seems "TSocket" is not even listed under Transport as you can see in the screenshot below.
[screenshot of available modules under Thrift Transport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDRF3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thrift 0.14 changed some names and the nested namespace structure. What was Thrift.Transport.TSocket is now Thrift.Transport.Client.TSocketTransport. See if swapping that fixes it.

If not check your project ref to the Thrift lib. Something like this may help (quoting "The Programmer's Guide to Apache Thrift"):

"To add the C# Apache Thrift library reference, right-click the References item in the project in the Solution Explorer and choose “Add Reference”. Next use the “Browse...” button to locate the Thrift.dll in thrift/lib/csharp/src/bin/Debug (or wherever). Make sure that there is a check next to the Thrift.dll entry in the Reference Manager dialog and then click OK. After a brief pause Intelisense errors should clear."

... or using the package manager:

"To add a Thrift.dll reference you can simply run the PackageManager install command:

```
PM> Install-Package -Prerelease ApacheThrift -ProjectName <your proj name here>

'ApacheThrift 1.0.0-dev' already installed.
Adding 'ApacheThrift 1.0.0-dev' to tradeServer.
Successfully added 'ApacheThrift 1.0.0-dev' to tradeServer.
"
```

Comment: I seem to have the Thrift.dll reference in the project already. Check the screenshot I attached now in the question. The only error seems to be on TSocket. It picks up TTransport and other references to thrift stuff just fine. I am not sure what is going on.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the complete error in the original question above. Thanks

Comment: As I added in the question above, it seems somehow there is no "TSocket"  under Thrift Transport in the screenshot I posted in the question.

Comment: Hey John, Just poking around and it looks like 0.14 changed some names in netstd. Try: TSocketTransport in Thrift.Transport.Client

Comment: YES! @codeSF. That worked. Thank you. If you can edit your answer to include that I will tag it as accepted.

Comment: Oh good! Sorry for the initial misdirect. Made the answer edits for suture readers.

Comment: I should add that using TSocketTransport and  wrapping the hostname and port in TcpClient from System.Net and passing that into the TSocketTransport constructor worked for me. It somehow did not work when I passed in the hostname and port directly.

Comment: Ha! That looks like a bug in the thrift constructor. This guy `TSocketTransport(string host, int port, TConfiguration config, int timeout = 0)` initializes the TcpClient correctly and this guy `TSocketTransport(IPAddress host, int port, TConfiguration config, int timeout = 0)` does not. Will try to get a patch submitted (feel free to beat me to it!! :-)